# With PostgreSQL how to determine the average completion time given two time stamps while accounting for nulls

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database I have an invitations table with the following fields:

```
Invitations: id, created_at, completed_at (timestamp)
```

I am working to write a PostgreSQL query that tells me the average completion time for invitations per weekly cohort:

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT  
    TRUNC(DATE_PART('day', CURRENT_DATE - i.created_at )/7)  AS weeks_ago,
    date(min(i.created_at)) AS "Date Start",
    date(max(i.created_at)) AS "Date End",
    avg(i.completed_at - i.created_at) as average_days_to_complete                
FROM invitations i
GROUP BY weeks_ago
ORDER BY weeks_ago ASC;
```

The problem with my query is this line:

```
`avg(i.completed_at - i.created_at) as average_days_to_complete`
```

The problem is this select statement is not ignoring invitations that were not completed, meaning `i.completed_at is NULL`

How can I update the above to only include invitations that were completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you want to treat them?  You can give them the current timestamp:

```
SELECT TRUNC(DATE_PART('day', CURRENT_DATE - i.created_at )/7)  AS weeks_ago,
       date(min(i.created_at)) AS "Date Start",
       date(max(i.created_at)) AS "Date End",
      avg(coalesce(i.completed_at, now()) - i.created_at) as average_days_to_complete                
FROM invitations i
GROUP BY weeks_ago
ORDER BY weeks_ago ASC;
```

If you want to ignore them, then your version does that:

```
avg(i.completed_at - i.created_at)
```

When `i.completed_at` is `NULL`, then the result is `NULL` and `avg()` ignores `NULL` values.

Comment: i want to ignore them, if the invitations haven't been completed they should not be included in the average.